# Schedule install of certificate

Tags: iis, iis-7, certificate

I'll be installing a new certificate in IIS in the near future. I don't want to do it during business hours, as it might disrupt our users. Nor do I want to stay late at work to install it. I'd like to have it installed overnight, and then the users can update their systems the next morning.

Is there a way to schedule the installation of a new certificate in IIS?

Comment: I know it’s not the main point of the question, but what do you mean by “may disrupt our users” and “users can update their systems the next morning”? If you swap a trusted cert with another valid one, no service disruption will occur.

Comment: @Marco By my understanding, some of our users are trusting the certificate itself, and not the chain or cert path, which means they will need to import the new certificate. Though, I might be misunderstanding how that works, and that would probably be the topic of another question.

Comment: I assumed the cert to be valid and thus already trusted by clients. If it’s a self signed or something, I understand your concerns.

Comment: normally a cert swap only takes a few mins, but this might help http://www.adamtheautomator.com/automating-iis-ssl-certificate-installation-with-powershell/